# How to use the custom comp function of std::lower_bound()?

Tags: c++, binary-search, custom-function, lower-bound

I want to specify to the lower_bound function that it should compare only the .first property of a pair and not both of them, as I assume it is default behavior.

In my situation, it's guaranteed the input is ordered, and I need a O(nlogn) solution. I'm not using `std::binary_search` because I need to access the position so I can get the .second value, as the code below shows.

I've read the documentation already, but I didn't find it clear, there were no specific examples there and a description not longer than a paragraph.

Here's my code, which is not producing the expected behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool comp(pair<string, int> i, string value) {
    return (i.first == value);
}

int main() {
    vector<pair<string, int>> books;

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        string name; int code;
        pair<string, int> livro;
        cin >> name >> code;
        books.push_back(make_pair(name, code));
    }

    int m;
    cin >> m;
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        string consult;
        cin >> consult;
        auto i = lower_bound(books.begin(), books.end(), consult, comp);
        if (i->first == consult) {
            if (i->second == 1) {
                cout << "Avaliable" << '\n';
            }
            else {
                cout << "Borrowed" << '\n';
            }
        }

        else {
            cout << "Not found" << '\n';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, `std::lower_bound` assumes the range is already sorted according to the passed `comp`. Maybe you are looking for `std::find_if` (linear search)?

Comment: The comparison function for `lower_bound` should return true if the first item is **less than** the second item. Seems clear enough that you want `find_if` not `lower_bound`.

Comment: @john My undestanding of lower_bound is that it, in an ordered list, it returns the first position of the searched element using binary search. I need a O(nlogn) solution. It's guaranteed that the input is ordered. I'm not using std::binary_search because I need to access the position so I can get the .second value, as the code shows. What I'm trying to do here is to specify to the function that it should compare only the .first property and not both of them.

Comment: @Jonas It wasn't obvious that the input is ordered. If so then `lower_bound` is possible. However it is still the case that the comparison object should return true if the first element is less than the second (not equal as you have). So your code should work if you replace `==` with `<` in `comp`. Haven't tested that though.

Comment: @john thank you very much, it worked. I can't see it clearly what exactly I did by doing this replacement. Would you briefly explain it as an answer?

Comment: @Jonas Imagine you were writing a binary search on (say) a vector of int. Now imagine that you have been told that your binary search code was only allowed to use `==` (no `<`, `>`, `<=` or `>=`). I'm sure you can see that is impossible. To do a binary search you need to know, at minimum, if an element of the vector is less than the element you are searching for. That is why you must supply a less than comparison to `lower_bound` when you use a custom comparator.

Comment: @Jonas Incidentally your code is still not correct. The test should be `if (i != books.end() && i->first == consult) {` because `lower_bound` can return `end()` if all the elements in the vector are less than the element being searched for.

Answer (score 0):

You should write comp func like below because you have to let lower_bound function know which value is bigger(or lesser) with two pair correctly in its algorithm.

```
bool comp(pair<string, int> i, string value) {
    return (i.first < value);
}
```

output is ok

```
3
aaa
Borrowed
bbb
Avaliable
ccc
Borrowed
```